# how i can convert xml to XSL

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am converting VB6 code to C#.net. IXSLProcessor xslProcessor.input takes DomDocument but I have XmlDocument. While casting (from xml to DomDocument) it throws an exception. Is it possible to convert XmlDocument to DomDocument? Code is

```
        Object vntRetVal;    
        ADODB.Stream objStream; 
        XSLTemplate xsl;  
        IXSLProcessor xslProcessor;
        DocSys.IField objField = null;
        String strFormatting=string.Empty;
        String strValue;
        Boolean blnManual;
        XmlElement nd;
        int m;
        int n;
        String[] bstr;
        object[] astr = null;

        objStream = new ADODB.Stream();
        objStream.Open()
        xslProcessor = xsl.createProcessor();
        xslProcessor.addParameter("mergeindex", m_Model.MailMerge.Items.Current);
        DOMDocument dom1 = new DOMDocument();
        dom1 =(DOMDocument)m_Model.Document.get_Data;
        xslProcessor.input = dom1;                               
        xslProcessor.output = objStream;                        
        xslProcessor.transform();

        objStream.Position = 0;
        strValue = objStream.ReadText();
```

Comment: see this thred for tips http://www.oxygenxml.com/forum/topic7001.html

Comment: also see this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307029